# imp.load_source() in Python

Tags: python, import, module

When is it useful to use `imp.load_source()` [method](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html) for importing  Python module? Has it some advantage in some scenario in opposite to normal importing with `import` keyword?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import` always looks in the following [order](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement):

1. already imported modules
2. import hooks
3. files in the locations in `sys.path`
4. builtin modules

If you want to import a module which would not be found by any of these mechanisms, but you know the filename, then you could use `imp.load_source()`. Or if you want to import a module that would be shadowed by an earlier import mechanism, for example if you want to import `foo` from a directory in `sys.path` but there is a custom import hook that would find its own version of `foo` first, then you could use `imp.load_source()` for that too. Basically it lets you control the source of the module's code in a way that `import` does not.

Comment: May I ask, what does `hooks` mean?

Comment: If you meant to ask about the import hooks I mentioned, it's a way of allowing Python to find modules in places or ways that it wouldn't ordinarily look. See [PEP 302](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/).